# java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF: address not bound to any interface

Tags: java, kubernetes, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am deploying Keycloak with the help of Helm Chart But Wildfly Stop with the following errors

> [0m[0m03:34:19,891 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread
> 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off
> patches include: none [0m[0m03:34:20,086 INFO
> [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56)
> MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster version 1.4.4.Final
> [0m[31m03:34:20,089 ERROR [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 56) MODCLUSTER000034: Failed to start advertise
> listener: java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF:
> address not bound to any interface    at
> java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSetOption0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSetOption(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:91)
> at
> java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.setOption(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:371)
> at
> java.base/java.net.MulticastSocket.setInterface(MulticastSocket.java:477)
> at
> org.jboss.mod_cluster.core@1.4.4.Final//org.jboss.modcluster.advertise.impl.AdvertiseListenerImpl.init(AdvertiseListenerImpl.java:151)
> at
> org.jboss.mod_cluster.core@1.4.4.Final//org.jboss.modcluster.advertise.impl.AdvertiseListenerImpl.start(AdvertiseListenerImpl.java:161)
> at
> org.jboss.mod_cluster.core@1.4.4.Final//org.jboss.modcluster.ModClusterService.init(ModClusterService.java:166)
> at
> org.wildfly.mod_cluster.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.mod_cluster.undertow.UndertowEventHandlerAdapterService.start(UndertowEventHandlerAdapterService.java:83)
> at
> org.wildfly.clustering.service@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsyncServiceConfigurator$AsyncService.lambda$start$0(AsyncServiceConfigurator.java:117)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)  at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
>
> [0m[0m03:34:20,095 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC
> service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https
> listening on [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8443 [0m[0m03:34:20,095 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta
> Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete [0m[0m03:34:20,194
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1)
> WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war"
> (runtime-name: "keycloak-server.war") [0m[0m03:34:20,197 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1)
> WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory
> /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments [0m[0m03:34:20,599 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
> [0m[0m03:34:20,599 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread
> 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source
> [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS] [0m[33m03:34:22,285 WARN
> [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56)
> JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket ManagedMulticastSocketBinding
> was set to 20.00MB, but the OS only allocated 16.78MB
> [0m[33m03:34:22,286 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 56) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket
> ManagedMulticastSocketBinding was set to 25.00MB, but the OS only
> allocated 16.78MB [0m[0m03:34:25,293 INFO
> [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56)
> keycloak-v6-0: no members discovered after 3003 ms: creating cluster
> as coordinator

In my Value.yaml i added

```
 - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: '-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0'
```

If i remove `JAVA_OPTS` it will fail to connect with DB as well and fail with following error

> 03:42:21,999 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
> 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> org.wildfly.network.interface.private:
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> org.wildfly.network.interface.private: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve
> interface private     at
> org.jboss.as.server@18.0.4.Final//org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:98)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
> at
> org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 03:42:22,092 ERROR
> [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
> Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address:
> ([("interface" => "private")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080:
> Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.network.interface.private" =>
> "WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private"}} 03:42:22,391 INFO
> [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010:
> Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
> 03:42:22,392 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)
> WFLYCTL0183: Service status report WFLYCTL0186:   Services which
> failed to start:      service org.wildfly.network.interface.private:
> WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface private WFLYCTL0448: 47
> additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing
> or failed 03:42:22,702 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot
> Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server 03:42:22,785 ERROR [org.jboss.as]
> (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: Keycloak 16.1.1 (WildFly Core
> 18.0.4.Final) started (with errors) in 18700ms - Started 471 of 930 services (54 services failed or missing dependencies, 694 services are
> lazy, passive or on-demand)

- Keycloak 16.1.1
- WildFly Core 18.0.4.Final
- Kubernets

Comment: In the first error looks like there is something not proper in the standalone.xml, could be the address definition is not defined (missing).

Comment: @Plain_Dude_Sleeping_Alone This Deployment Through the Helm Chart ,Downloaded from https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/releases/download/keycloak-18.1.0/keycloak-18.1.0.tgz.If u want standalone.xml i will add that also.

Comment: It's just a hint (sort of). Something is not configured correctly in the definition. I have no idea about the Keyloack. But if you see the error it complained about something with `<Interface ..>` and  `<inet-address..>` in the standalone.xml. Look at  that `Failed to start advertise listener: java.net.SocketException: bad argument for IP_MULTICAST_IF: address not bound to any interface at java.base/java.net.`

Comment: In standalone.xml ..its something like this `<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a new private interface in the interfaces section.

```
    <interface name="private">
        <inet-address value="<your private address>"/>
    </interface>
```

Comment: In Single machine deployment ,it can be done .But how it can be achieve in Kubernetes environment ?